# Schedule import to salesforce

Tags: data-loader

HI,

I am getting daily csv files from other system. it contains the information of account name, contact detials, opportunity details and quote details i want import the records for every 30mins into salesforce, may i know how can i import those records into salesforce for every 30mins.can any one explain me.

Answer (score 3):

Another tool you'll want to look into is Jitterbit.  They have a "cloud based" data loader tool, which allows you to schedule imports.  You'll have to download a client for configuring your dataload and which Salesforce instance it loads into, but the scheduling interface makes scheduling your data loads painless.

Here's a screenshot of the scheduling setup in Jitterbit's Cloud Dataloader:

[image]

Here's a link to get you started with Jitterbit:

http://www.jitterbit.com/solutions/salesforce-integration/salesforce-data-loader/

Comment: may i know  jitterbit is free tool..??

Comment: The cloud data loader is free.  It even says so at the bottom of the page I linked to.  They have some other integration tools that are not free, though.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of integration tools and techniques.

From my view your best option is [dataloader-cli](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Using_Data_Loader_from_the_command_line) + cron. Basically you can create a cron and call dataloader command line in that cron.

Other good option is [dataloader.io](https://dataloader.io/scheduling), now it supports schedule tasks on the free version. But I don't think that you will achieve that frequency.

Comment: cron is different tool or dataloader-cli both are same

Comment: both are different, you have to combine them, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron